# Visual Studio debugger crashes when viewing a variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Below is what I get shortly before VS Debugger crashes.  When i don't have the debugger view it, it throws a segfault in the set function. The debugger has been working all day, on this same stuff too.  Any ideas?

[image: Visual Studio Debug Session]

Object i am viewing:

```
[DataContract]
public class SvnUrl
{

    public string _type;
    public string _acronym;
    public string _location;
    public string _url;
    public int _foundstatus;

    [DataMember]
    public string type
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set { _type = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string acronym
    {
        get { return _acronym; }
        set { _acronym = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set { _location = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string url
    {
        get { return _url; }
        set { _url = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int foundstatus
    {
        get { return _foundstatus; }
        set { _foundstatus = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the `setFunction` method? The code you have show doesn't make much sense.

Comment: After a really long night of coding i had a similar problem with visual studio. Of course when i figured out what it was, it was my fault. I had a property which calls the property again, while implementing CollectionBase, which causes an infinite loop. So i would say, double check all your properties and all side effects.

Comment: try restarting vs? also, as an aside, is there any reason you aren't using auto properties?

Comment: Try ordering your `[DataMember]`'s maybe? I had a similar issue that I seem to recall was fixed by using the `Order` property

Comment: @user1026857,  this is essentially the entire function, aside from the class declaration and includes.

Comment: @saus,  No clue what auto properties are, i'm just kind of maintaining some c# code.  Ill look them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you typed the example identical to your code and you don't really have `get { return location; }` in that location property (note the missing `_` thus recursing infinitely)?

Comment: i did at one point, but after it was fixed and vs was restarted, it didn't fix anything.
Im going to try again this morning.

Comment: Alright, i think you nailed it.  My environment must not have been building the new code.  Ive been having a problem with that.  The fix was to fix the infinite recursion, check into my scm, delete all my local files, re checkout.